# Unable to find fallback package folder

Tags: asp.net

When I run the ASP.NET project, got the following error.

> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.102\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(267,5): error MSB4018: NuGet.Packaging.Core.PackagingException: Unable to find fallback package folder 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Xamarin\NuGet'.

Comment: Due to the flexibility of NuGet configuration system, it is possible that something on your machine inserted a non-existent `'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Xamarin\NuGet'` into the fall back folder settings. Since you might not be able to locate the actual setting file to reset this, you can follow the answer to create this folder as a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a folder at the location it is asking for, i.e.,  `'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Xamarin\NuGet'`. For example, I added a blank folder here: `C:\Users\USERNAME\NuGetRepository` and got passed an error very similar to this.

I have no idea why this works (yet) but I no longer get the error message: `The "ResolvePackageAssets" task failed unexpectedly Unable to find fallback package folder C:\Users\USERNAME\NuGetRepository` (where username is my Windows username) when trying to Build a simple C# .Net 7 project that a colleague gave me.